# why is this line appearing after installing kubuntu-desktop?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, plank

I thought to give kubuntu-desktop a try on my xubuntu. So i installed it. On reboot, a white line appears on my screen. I removed all kubuntu-desktop that i previously installed but the line still remains. Here is a screenshot. How do i remove it?
[image]

my currently running ..........

```
android@android:~$ sudo python ps_mem.py
 Private  +   Shared  =  RAM used   Program

160.0 KiB +  42.5 KiB = 202.5 KiB   gnome-pty-helper
224.0 KiB +  31.0 KiB = 255.0 KiB   acpid
244.0 KiB +  28.0 KiB = 272.0 KiB   sh
284.0 KiB +  45.5 KiB = 329.5 KiB   agetty
332.0 KiB +  46.5 KiB = 378.5 KiB   irqbalance
316.0 KiB +  88.5 KiB = 404.5 KiB   cron
400.0 KiB +  87.0 KiB = 487.0 KiB   rtkit-daemon
408.0 KiB +  81.5 KiB = 489.5 KiB   systemd-timesyncd
432.0 KiB +  88.0 KiB = 520.0 KiB   dbus-launch
532.0 KiB +  20.5 KiB = 552.5 KiB   ssh-agent
232.0 KiB + 473.0 KiB = 705.0 KiB   bamfdaemon-dbus
580.0 KiB + 135.5 KiB = 715.5 KiB   gvfsd-metadata
604.0 KiB + 129.5 KiB = 733.5 KiB   xfconfd
688.0 KiB + 110.0 KiB = 798.0 KiB   dconf-service
700.0 KiB + 206.0 KiB = 906.0 KiB   gconfd-2
772.0 KiB + 137.5 KiB = 909.5 KiB   gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
788.0 KiB + 124.5 KiB = 912.5 KiB   gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
848.0 KiB + 141.5 KiB = 989.5 KiB   dnsmasq
940.0 KiB +  69.5 KiB =   1.0 MiB   systemd-logind
376.0 KiB + 651.0 KiB =   1.0 MiB   avahi-daemon (2)
980.0 KiB + 230.0 KiB =   1.2 MiB   sudo
  1.0 MiB + 196.0 KiB =   1.2 MiB   gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
  1.0 MiB + 312.0 KiB =   1.3 MiB   gvfsd-trash
  1.3 MiB +  90.0 KiB =   1.4 MiB   bluetoothd
  1.4 MiB + 173.0 KiB =   1.5 MiB   accounts-daemon
  1.2 MiB + 349.5 KiB =   1.5 MiB   thermald
  1.5 MiB +  79.5 KiB =   1.6 MiB   rsyslogd
  1.2 MiB + 450.5 KiB =   1.6 MiB   gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
  1.3 MiB + 478.5 KiB =   1.8 MiB   mount.ntfs (2)
  2.0 MiB +  39.0 KiB =   2.0 MiB   dhclient
  2.0 MiB + 130.0 KiB =   2.2 MiB   systemd-udevd
  1.6 MiB + 692.0 KiB =   2.2 MiB   (sd-pam)
  1.9 MiB + 452.5 KiB =   2.3 MiB   gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
  1.7 MiB + 621.0 KiB =   2.3 MiB   panel-4-systray
  1.7 MiB + 631.0 KiB =   2.4 MiB   cups-browsed
  2.0 MiB + 496.0 KiB =   2.5 MiB   bash
  2.3 MiB + 222.0 KiB =   2.5 MiB   polkitd
  2.0 MiB + 782.5 KiB =   2.8 MiB   panel-9-netload
  2.3 MiB + 509.5 KiB =   2.8 MiB   dbus-daemon (2)
  2.8 MiB +  97.5 KiB =   2.9 MiB   systemd-journald
  1.8 MiB +   1.1 MiB =   2.9 MiB   whoopsie
  2.9 MiB + 144.0 KiB =   3.0 MiB   gvfsd-fuse
  2.8 MiB + 295.5 KiB =   3.1 MiB   gvfsd
  2.3 MiB + 795.0 KiB =   3.1 MiB   lightdm (2)
  2.5 MiB + 669.0 KiB =   3.2 MiB   wpa_supplicant
  2.8 MiB + 720.5 KiB =   3.5 MiB   xfsettingsd
  3.6 MiB + 362.0 KiB =   3.9 MiB   ModemManager
  2.9 MiB +   1.2 MiB =   4.1 MiB   xfce4-power-manager (2)
  3.8 MiB + 510.0 KiB =   4.3 MiB   upowerd
  4.0 MiB + 341.0 KiB =   4.3 MiB   gnome-keyring-daemon
  3.7 MiB + 686.5 KiB =   4.4 MiB   xfce4-volumed
  2.5 MiB +   2.3 MiB =   4.8 MiB   systemd (2)
  3.8 MiB +   1.1 MiB =   4.9 MiB   polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
  4.2 MiB + 689.0 KiB =   4.9 MiB   panel-6-actions
  4.4 MiB + 722.5 KiB =   5.1 MiB   panel-5-power-m
  4.2 MiB +   1.0 MiB =   5.2 MiB   xfce4-panel
  5.2 MiB + 365.0 KiB =   5.6 MiB   udisksd
  4.9 MiB + 746.0 KiB =   5.6 MiB   pulseaudio
  4.3 MiB +   1.4 MiB =   5.7 MiB   light-locker
  5.2 MiB + 662.0 KiB =   5.9 MiB   xfce4-session
  5.1 MiB +   1.3 MiB =   6.3 MiB   panel-1-whisker
  6.1 MiB +   1.2 MiB =   7.3 MiB   xfce4-notifyd
  6.5 MiB +   1.0 MiB =   7.5 MiB   NetworkManager
  7.2 MiB +   1.8 MiB =   9.0 MiB   bamfdaemon
  7.8 MiB +   1.3 MiB =   9.1 MiB   xfce4-terminal
  6.8 MiB +   2.4 MiB =   9.1 MiB   panel-17-pulsea
  7.9 MiB +   1.5 MiB =   9.4 MiB   xfwm4
 11.1 MiB +  49.5 KiB =  11.1 MiB   snapd
 10.5 MiB +   2.5 MiB =  13.1 MiB   nm-applet
 12.8 MiB +   3.1 MiB =  15.9 MiB   plank
 17.6 MiB +   2.4 MiB =  20.0 MiB   Thunar
 18.7 MiB +   1.7 MiB =  20.4 MiB   xfdesktop
 25.4 MiB +   2.8 MiB =  28.2 MiB   gnome-system-monitor
 27.8 MiB +   1.6 MiB =  29.4 MiB   viewnior
 43.5 MiB +   4.4 MiB =  48.0 MiB   Xorg
 56.0 MiB +   4.2 MiB =  60.1 MiB   geary
731.0 MiB +  75.2 MiB = 806.2 MiB   opera (12)
---------------------------------
                          1.2 GiB
=================================
```

Comment: i have just notice that if i open any picture and make it full screen .. here i tried with feh ... the line disappears. It appears back again when i come out of the full screen.

Comment: I might recommend trying to determine the program that is causing the issue.  Go to your task manger or system monitor or whatever and kill anything kde related (provided it doesn't give serious warnings).

Comment: Maybe exit / close the dock you're using ? Could be related to that.

Comment: yes its the 'plank' . Where could it have gone wrong? When I load it back again the line comes back.

Comment: kubuntu-desktop must have changed some settings. plank works fine when i switch user.

Comment: problem solved... "show shadow under dock windows" in compositor is all that i had to disable.

Comment: You should write that as the answer and add the 'plank' tag. I've met that humorous problem myself last month (and fixed it in the same way that you did), but only after a night considering reinstalling my whole system because I cannot find any solution on the Internet :D

Answer (score 0):

"show shadow under dock windows" in compositor is all that i had to disable.

window manager tweaks > compositor > show shadow under dock windows